# Can't able to get the minimum value from the temperature array. What might be the problem?

Tags: javascript

```js
const temperature = [3, -2, -6, -1, 'error', 9, 13, 17, 15, 14, 9, 5];

const calcTempAmplitude = function (temp) {
  let max = temp[0];
  let min = temp[0];

  for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    const currtemp = temp[i];

    if (typeof currtemp !== 'number') continue;

    if (currtemp > max) max = currtemp;
    if (currtemp < max) min = currtemp;
  }
  console.log(max, min);
};

calcTempAmplitude(temperature);
```

The output should be: 17 -6 but instead, I am getting 17 5. what's wrong with my code?

Comment: `if (currtemp < max) min = currtemp;` Do you mean `if (currtemp < min) min = currtemp;`?

Answer (score 1):

The second `if` statement is wrong it should compare to `min`

```
if (currtemp < min) min = currtemp;
```

```js
const temperature = [3, -2, -6, -1, 'error', 9, 13, 17, 15, 14, 9, 5];

const calcTempAmplitude = function (temp) {
  let max = temp[0];
  let min = temp[0];

  for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    const currtemp = temp[i];

    if (typeof currtemp !== 'number') continue;

    if (currtemp > max) max = currtemp;
    if (currtemp < min) min = currtemp;
  }
  console.log(max, min);
};

calcTempAmplitude(temperature);
```